# Conjecture on the units digits of odd powers

Tags: number-theory

I was playing around with pen and paper and noticed an intriguing pattern in the units digits of $1^r, 2^r, \dots, 10^r$ for various $r$. For even powers, the digits seemed to "reflect" around $5$, as is shown here for $r=2$:
$$\color{blue}{1} \quad \color{green}{4} \quad \color{red}{9} \quad 6 \quad \color{orange}{5} \quad 6 \quad \color{red}{9} \quad \color{green}{4} \quad \color{blue}{1} \quad 0$$

For odd $r$, I formed the following conjecture:

*The units digits of $1^r, 2^r, 3^r,\dots,10^r$ where $r \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd form the set $\{0,1,2,\cdots,9\}$*.

I'm no number theorist, so don't know where to start proving this conjecture. From $r=1$, it would make sense that there is some "rotation" of the digits which occurs, but I'm not sure. Could anyone help?

Comment: If $n$ is even then $10\,|\,(10-j)^n-j^n$.

Comment: You conjecture about odd $r$ is correct. In fact, there are only two cases, $r=4k+1,$ then the last digit of $a^r$ is the same as the last digit of $a.$ And if $r=4k+3$ then the last digit of $a^r$ is $0,1,8,7,4,5,6,3,2,9$ if $a$ ends with $0,1,2,\dots,9$ respectively.

Comment: Notice if $a = 1,2,3,4$ and if $b = 9,8,7,6$ then $b = 10-a$.  So $(10-a)^r = \sum_{k=0}^r c_k*10^{k}*(-a)^{r-k}$.  As we are only interested in the unit terms we don't about any of the $c_k*10^{k}*(-a)^{r-k}$ terms where $k> 0$ and only care about the $(-a)^r$ term.  So the unit term of $b^r = (10-a)^r$ is the same as the unit term of $(-a)^r$.  If $r$ is even $(-a)^r=a^r$ and $a^r$ and $b^r$ have the same unit terms. other wise....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is true.

Suppose $r$ is odd and $x^r \equiv y^r \mod 10$.  Thus $x^r \equiv y^r \mod 2$ and also mod $5$.

Mod $2$ it's easy to see that $x$ and $y$ are either both even or both odd, i.e. $x \equiv y \mod 2$.

If $x^r \equiv y^r \equiv 0 \mod 5$, then $x \equiv 0 \equiv y \mod 5$; otherwise, $y$ is invertible mod $5$, and $(x y^{-1})^r \equiv 1 \mod 5$.
But the multiplicative group mod $5$ has order $4$, so the only element that has order dividing an odd number is $1$, i.e. $x y^{-1} \equiv 1 \mod 5$ and $x \equiv y \mod 5$.

We conclude that $x \equiv y \mod 2$ and also mod $5$, so $x \equiv y \mod 10$.
This says the map $x \to x^r$ is injective on the integers mod $10$.  Since it's an
injective map on a finite set, it is also surjective.

Comment: That was even more interesting than I'd anticipated! Thanks